# Use UIScrollView to show photo ,load the photo when scroll to it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

I use the scrollview to show my photos, I want to know how to realize the mechanism that when I scroll to the photo then it is loaded so that to save the memory. Can anyone give me some suggestion or related material? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this by yourself, use the

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

dont forget to define your scrollview frame, so that the paging is not messy

after that you load the images if the scrollview reach certain offset

the code will looked somewhat like this :

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 500) //for example if you choose to put your image in y:500
    {
        //load your images here you could load it in the main thread or use dispatch queue if you load it from web
    }
}
```

by doing this, when you scroll your scrollView 500points downward, it will load the images you want.

this is only the basic logic, you can do many thing from here onward. i'd say don't rely too much on open source git, try making things works yourself, your way. if by then you still don't find out how, then go try the git. but i recommend learning how the code works rather than only using it plainly for  what it does :3

edit : you might want to set a method to remove the images from superview after you scroll out of the images rank to save out memory, and set out some boolean flag so that the images dont load twice or more

Comment: Really thanks! I am considering that how to deal with the images scroll out (the images I have browsed), I do not understand that you say "set out some boolean flag so that the images don`t load twice or more", can you tell me the details how this work?

Comment: basically, when you scroll to a certain offset, you gonna load the image right??? what happen when you scroll down, and then you scroll up, and then down again??? the code will react to the method calling your image, it will load twice and more because you can scroll again to that offset.  to prevent this, you need to set a YES NO logic. for instance, create a BOOL variable named "imageLoaded" and define it as NO. after that on the scroll logic, add if(!imageLoaded){ // load your images ; imageLoaded = YES}, this way, after you load the image, the flag will turn YES and image wont load anymore

Comment: I know what you mean now. I want to know is it necessary to release the images that have passed by? just like this: if(contentoff.y < 550){release the image}. if it is true, when I scroll back , it seems that i should load twice.

Comment: if you using ARC there's no need to use release as the program will determines whether your objects need to be release or not. if not however, you can choose between releasing it or just remove it from the view, because if you release it, then it means you must includes your uiimageview alloc inside the image adding progress

Answer (score 1):

you may use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)   , and you don't have to worry about cache and etc

Web Image
This library provides a category for UIImageVIew with support for remote images coming from the web.

It provides:

An UIImageView category adding web image and cache management to the Cocoa Touch framework
An asynchronous image downloader
An asynchronous memory + disk image caching with automatic cache expiration handling
A guarantee that the same URL won't be downloaded several times
A guarantee that bogus URLs won't be retried again and again
Performances!